# MacBook Air Hard drive crashed (2013 Model)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

Is it possible to replace the hard drive for a 2013 MacBook Air? Where can I purchase a new hard drive?

If not, is it possible to run it with a portable hard drive?

I purchased it in 2014 (refurbished). So, it's probably 2013 model and not under Apple Care. Apple customer service told me that my hard drive has crashed.

Does Apple sells hard drives?

Comment: YES, it is possible see here https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/macbook-air-faq/macbook-air-mid-2013-how-to-replace-upgrade-ssd-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace the hard drive for a 2013 MacBook Air?

No. MacBook Air hard drive is generally not end-user replaceable. However, if you feel comfortable tinkering with hardware, you can find a hard drive replacement guide by iFixit [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/15181). Make sure you procure a compatible drive and the recommended tools.

> If not, is it possible to run it with a portable hard drive?

Yes, it is possible to install macOS on an external drive and boot off it.

> Does Apple sells hard drives?

No.

Comment: iFixit shows differently: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/15181

Answer (score 2):

**You can** replace the SSD (Solid State Drive, it is not a hard drive with spinning disk)!

.... with a model from OWC yourself if you know your way around embedded hardware.

Apple does not sell parts to individuals, but an AASP or APSP (Apple Service Providers) can replace it for you with an Apple part.

The SSDs are **not** compatible with m.2 or mSATA, you have to use the specific MacBook Air SSD for your model. Major MacBook Air releases also have different SSDs due to incompatible upgrades (protocol upgrades and electrical upgrades).

Sites like [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2013+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/15181) have guides that can assist you with this.

See some instructions here https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/macbook-air-faq/macbook-air-mid-2013-how-to-replace-upgrade-ssd-storage.html

Comment: Friendly advice...you use a lots of acronyms.. :)

Comment: Ah yes, risk of the trade ;-)